# Find an item within an array in a collection with the highest score overall and return with that score

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Schema:

```js
const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  address: {
    building: String,
    coord: [Number, Number],
    street: String,
    zipcode: String,
  },
  borough: String,
  cuisine: String,
  grades: [{ date: Date, grade: String, score: Number }],
  name: String,
  restaurant_id: String,
});
```

I am trying to find a restaurant with the highest `grades.score` and return what that score is.

What I've tried doing:

```js
Restaurant.find({}, { "grades.score": 1, _id: 0 }).sort({ "grades.score": -1 }).limit(1).exec((err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

What it returns:

```js
[
  {
    grades: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

What I want:

```js
[
   {
      score: 131
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- you can use the `$max` aggregate operator that works as accumulator and on arrays like here
- this is for the local(inside the document array) `max-score` if you want for the global(in all the collection) you can sort desc by `max-score`
  and `$limit 1`

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6312797e78a49d8782851498)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$project": {"_id": 0, "max-score": {"$max": "$grades.score"}}}])
```